How to add/change QStackedLayout without changing current layout?
I am making a Sudoku app, and I am trying to show text boxes (line edit) on top of sudoku grid. To do this, I have a 2-page stackedWidget, one with the grid and one with the text boxes. Everything is already organized in the event of a window resize, and now whenever I try to add the QStackedLayout (to enable ShowAll), it changes the window layout entirely.


The only difference between the two attached pictures is this set of code (and it doesn't even stack both as far as I can tell):
    QStackedLayout * layoutt = new QStackedLayout;
    layoutt->addWidget(ui->stackedWidget);
    layoutt->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackingMode::StackAll);


The third image is the structure I think is being destroyed when I assign the stackedWidget to my new layout.

There doesn't seem to be a way to put a QStackedLayout in the designer, and I'm not entirely sure how to just replace my stackedWidget in its layout with a QStackedLayout, with the stackedWidget as its child.
The overall goal is to get both the sudoku and the text box pages visible, which I think requires QStackedLayout, which means I need to add QStackedLayout in place of stackedWidget, and set stackedWidget as its child.
Edit:
Here is the current state of the code:
mainwindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QStackedLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Show both the Sudoku image (page 2) and the textboxes (page 1)
    ((QStackedLayout *)ui->stackedWidget->layout())->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

main.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Set up the application.
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Pull from the style sheet (if it exists).
    QString styles = readTextFile(":/styles.css");
    if(styles.length() > 0)
    {
        a.setStyleSheet(styles);
    }


    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Sudoku Solver");
 
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

Form layout:


StyleSheet (probably not relevant, but included just in case):
QPushButton#SolveButton
{
image: url(:/Resources/pushbutton.png);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

QPushButton#SolveButton:pressed
{
image: url(:/Resources/pushbutton_pressed.png);
color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

QPushButton#SolveButton:hover
{
border: none;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
padding: 2px;
}

QPushButton#HelpButton
{
image: url(:/Resources/Blue_question_mark_icon.svg.png);
}

QPushButton#HelpButton:pressed
{
image: url(:/Resources/Blue_question_mark_icon_pressed.png);
}

QPushButton#HelpButton:hover
{
border-radius: 30px;
}

QPushButton#TabButton
{
image: url(:/Resources/active.png);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border: none;
}

QLabel#SudokuGrid
{
    image: url(:/Resources/blank-sudoku-grid.png);
}


QStackedWidget is simply a widget with its own QStackedLayout. It makes no sense to add a QStackedWidget to a QStackedLayout. Just access the layout of the existing QStackedWidget and call its setStackingMode().

Hello again! So, I am trying to access it with ui->stackedWidget->layout(), and I am getting the error "QStackedLayout::addItem: Only widgets can be added".
I am accessing stackedWidget.layout(), assigning it to a variable by casting QLayout to QStackedLayout, and then setting the stacking mode. Is there some other way to do what you said to? QStackedWidget doesn't have a member setStackingMode() directly.

QStackedLayout lay = QStackedLayout(ui->stackedWidget->layout());     lay.setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll);
If it helps.

That's not casting. You're creating a new QStackedLayout and adding to the existing one.

Sorry, got the parentheses wrong. The following gets rid of the error message, but it still doesn't show both pages simultaneously:                                   QStackedLayout * lay = (QStackedLayout *)ui->stackedWidget->layout();
lay->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll);

Then please provide a more complete [mre] that shows how you try to achieve the above, including the latest modification.

What is the current index of the stacked widget? Because if it's the page showing the image, and that image (as I assume, based on your screenshots) is not transparent, it would obviously hide everything behind it, don't you think? The current page is always on top. If the text fields are in the first page, then you should set that as the current one, either in the code or, more appropriately, directly in Designer.

I have the same problem regardless of which page I have showing when the app begins. The page that is showing is the only one that appears, DESPITE having QStackedLayout::ShowAll. The page with the text boxes is just an empty page with empty text boxes, so there shouldn't be any issue drawing the sudoku image under that. Nevertheless, I either get text boxes that I can manipulate, or I get a Sudoku image and I can't click into anything.

Please include the UI file.

Text is too long to add, but all files are stored here: https://github.com/HayatoTenryuu/Qt-Sudoku-Solver

Remove the stylesheet property from the main window. You're forcing the background of all widgets to full white, so you cannot obviously see what's behind. Always use proper selector types and avoid generic properties for complex widgets and containers (including the window) as they are propagated to children indiscriminately, no matter their type. In your case, if you want set the background color of the window to white, then just use #centralwidget { background: white; }.

Note that we don't normally accept questions having code in external resources (especially repositories that may make the post invalid). At least try to reduce the UI to what actually matters: a couple of widgets shown in the stackedwidget. It doesn't really matter if it's not identical to your final program (since the issue clearly doesn't require to have 9x9 line edits or everything else): what matters is to make the problem reproducible.

Good to know, thank you!
